# createSelector returning null, but only in tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, ngrx

I have a Jasmine unit test on my ngrx selectors. The first works fine, but the second always returns undefined, even though I can see that the reducer is executing correctly.

The selectors look like this:

```
export const selectProductState = createFeatureSelector<State, ProductState> (
  'product'
);

export const selectProductDetailsState = createSelector(
  selectProductState,
  ((state: ProductState) => state.product)
);

export const selectProduct = createSelector(
  selectProductDetailsState,
  ((state: ProductDetails) => state.product)
);
```

and my tests look like this:

```
describe('selectProductDetailsState', () => {
  it('should return state of product store slice', () => {
    let result;

    store.pipe(
      select(fromSelectors.selectProductDetailsState)
    ).subscribe(value => ( result = value ));

    expect(result).toEqual(undefined);

    store.dispatch(new fromActions.LoadProductSummarySuccess(product));

    expect(result).toEqual(
      product
    );
  });
});

describe('selectProduct', () => {
  it('should return the product state', () => {
    let result;

    store.pipe(
      select(fromSelectors.selectProduct)
    ).subscribe(value => ( result = value ));

    expect(result).toEqual(undefined);

    store.dispatch(new fromActions.LoadProductSummarySuccess(product));

    expect(result).toEqual(product);
  });
});
```

The `selectProductDetailsState` returns the product as expected, but the `selectProduct` returns undefined.

### If you need any more of my code, just shout what you need.

Here is how I setting up the store in the tests:

```
describe('Product summary selectors', () => {
  let store: Store<State>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot(fromStore.reducers)
      ]
    });

    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  });
  // tests go here
})
```

Comment: How are you setting up your store while testing? Do you use the same initial state as your app?

Also it looks like both of your selectors are returning the same `.product` property on a slice of state - is this a mistake?

Comment: No, it's a suspect design rather than a mistake. There is a `product.product`....How do you set the initial state in a test environment? I have added code above to show how I'm setting up.

Comment: How do I init the store properly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to solve this by including an empty root store, and then importing `StoreModule.forFeature` for your scenario it would look something like this:

```
describe('Product summary selectors', () => {
  let store: Store<State>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        StoreModule.forFeature('products', fromStore.reducers)
      ]
    });

    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  });
  // tests go here
})
```

Not sure if its the best solution, but it's the only thing that worked for me.